How to mock class functions of class instantiated during test execution
I cannot seem to wrap my head around mocking in phpunit. I have a test like this where I try to mock the execute method of my Curl Wrapper Class "CurlRequest".
/** @test */
public function check_invalid_connection()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(CurlRequest::class)
        ->onlyMethods(['execute'])
        ->setConstructorArgs(["bla"])
        ->getMock();

    $mock->method("execute")
        ->willThrowException(new Exception("Bla"));

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/my-api-call');
}

Within this API call the following code is executed
$req = new CurlRequest("any-url");
$req->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD,"user-password");
$req->setOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'MLSD');
$req->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
$response = $req->execute();
die($response);

My expectation would be, that the mock leads to throwing an execption during the ->execute call. However, this is not happening.
I cannot seem to find a good example where someone trys not to directly call the functions of the $mock they just created.
However, the constructor args seem to work as expected - when creating a new instance it will have "bla" as constructor arg.

Did you mean to call $mock->json() instead of $this->json()?

I believe the main problem here is that you're not using mocked component (in your example stored under $mock variable). Looking at the code:
/** @test */
public function check_invalid_connection()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(CurlRequest::class)
        ->onlyMethods(['execute'])
        ->setConstructorArgs(["bla"])
        ->getMock();

    $mock->method("execute")
        ->willThrowException(new Exception("Bla"));

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/my-api-call');
}

There is no chance for $mock to being executed. You have to rewrite your logic in a way, which would allow using of $mock instead of new CurlRequest.
That is why "testability" quite often works as a metric of your architecture quality: if it's easy to test - then probably it's organized good.
What can I suggest you? The easiest way would be to pass CurlRequest as a parameter to json() method. Then in test instead of new instance of CurlRequest you will be able to pass a mock.

I'm coming from the node world where a mock of a class (from within in a test) can also automatically mock all later instanciations, but it seems that this is not possible with php. Passing it to the json method will not help, as I would have to pass it down very deep - I guess I'll try a facade then I guess

@Frnak Well, I'd recommend you to use DI in PHP (for example, by using this library https://php-di.org/). But for that you'd need to rewrite your code a bit. But then you will be able to do many things (including testing) properly. In case of tests, for example, you will be able to pass mocked instance to the "container", and all other components will use it.
